# Excel: Search data in a column with multiple results

Tags: macos, excel, search

I have two worksheets, both have the same column 'Code'.
Worksheet 1 has multiple rows with the same code, along with a column named 'Status' which can be "Approved" or something else.

So I'd like to search for the code from worksheet 2 in worksheet 1, and if there is a row in worksheet 1 with that code and the status "Approved", then the corresponding column in worksheet 2 will get an "Yes".

I know I could accomplish this by using macros, but I'd rather (if possible) use Excel built-in functions. I tried to change some VBA codes I found online and ended up with many errors because some functions are different in Excel 2011 (for Mac OS X), and I'd like to make this as portable as possible.

I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with `SumProduct` -

Suppose your worksheets look as follows:

Sheet1:

```
ColA     ColB
Code1    Approved
Code2    Declined
Code2    Approved
...
```

Sheet2:

```
ColA     ColB
Code1    =IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$27=Sheet2!A1),--(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$27="Approved"))>0,"Yes","No")
```

Of course change the `$A$27` & `$B$27` references in the formula to cover as many cells as you have in `Sheet1`, but this should give you what you want and it is cross platform.

Hope this does the trick!

Comment: Yes, it did! I spent ages googling around and all I could find was VBA code. Never thought SUMPRODUCT would do it. A thousand thanks!